# Suckless utilities give XOpenIM failed error

Tags: xorg, i3, suckless-terminal

whenever i try to run a suckless app like **dmenu** or **suckless** terminal it gives the following error:

```
XOpenIM failed. Could not open input device.
```

how can i fix this error and be able to run dmenu?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by doing

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
```

I put this line in my ~/.bashrc and it works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have any cruft in `pacman.conf`, i.e.

```
NoExtract = locale...
```

Changing locale to `en_US-UTF-8`, reboot, then back to `en_GB-UTF-8` and reboot, worked for me.